# installing wifi adapter driver in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

how to install the drivers for usb adapter in raspberry pi (i am using raspbian wheezy) i am using usb wireless 802.II n wifi adapter. i tried the lsusb command but i am not able to get the device id  of wifi adapter.when i tried using  iwlist scan command ,wlan is not displayed instead only lo and eth 0 is displayed please help ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[image]I see three reasons for this to happen:

1. You have another device connected to the second USB port which needs a lot of power and the WLAN adapter doesn't get enough power any more. Try to connect the WLAN adapter or second USB device or both via an active USB hub to your pi
2. Your WLAN adapter is broken. Try to connect it on your desktop or labtop and check whether lsusb returns some details.
3. You have a very exotic WLAN adapter. Please post more details about your WLAN adapter. Maybe your seller has a webpage describing the WLAN adapter ?

Comment: even in desktop it does not give the id number, only shown that it is attached on bus no.

Comment: Would you please copy/paste the output you get executing lsusb?

Comment: screenshot has been attached. usb adapter is attached on bus 003

Comment: It No 3 :-)

That's what I usually do when I know the ID of the device which causes an issue: I paste following string 'id "1487:7601" linux' into my internet search machine and got for your id multiple hits where people had the same issue.

For example I got http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=73298 http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-148f7601-wifi-adaptor-installation http://superuser.com/questions/774554/linux-unable-to-get-usb-wifi-drivers-to-work-or-compile

Comment: yeah i found it thanks a lot :) but now after all configuration it does not shows that wifi name in scan list of my cell phone ? help